# What is the difference between ŋ͡͡j and ɲ?

Tags: phonology, ipa

I was thinking about how a "b̃" is the same thing as an "m" and a "s̪" is the same thing as a "θ". Maybe the same applies to ŋ͡͡j and ɲ?

Comment: I don't quite agree, but you could define your usage as such. [s] usually stands for a sibilant and [θ] doesn't.

Comment: You should also keep in mind that the /s/ in varieties of English, German, Norwegian and Swedish is dental(ized) but it still doesn't clash with [θ].